# Do I need to match the column order of my CREATE TABLE statement to that of my import data sheet?

Tags: postgresql, import-from-excel

I have an Excel CSV data sheet and I would like it to be imported into a new PostgreSQL table.

The Excel CSV data sheet has the columns in this order:

```
OrderDate, Region, Rep, Item, Units, Unit Price
```

This is my CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE officesupplies (
region varchar(20)
order_date,
rep_first_name varchar(30),
unit_price float
units float
)
```

Notice how the order of my columns in my Create Table statement do not match the Excel. I've tested this and it does not work but I'm wondering the 'why' behind it not being able to import. Just wondering, thanks in advance!

Comment: There are three commas, a type, a space and a semicolon missing from your table definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the columns in `COPY`. That way you can load data where the column order is different from your table.

In your case, you should use

```
COPY officesupplies
   (order_date, region, rep_first_name, ...)
FROM 'filenaame';
```

I see that you have a column `Item` in your file that does not seem to match any table colum. That won't work — in that case you will have to load the data into a –staging table” first or use third party software like pgLoader.

Comment: How would the syntax look? I tried using this: 
copy officesupplies (region, orderdate, rep_first_name, unit_price, units)
FROM 'C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\officesupplies.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
and I got this error message:

    ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "4-Jul-14"
    CONTEXT:  COPY officesupplies, line 2, column unit_price: "4-Jul-14"
    SQL state: 22P02

Comment: I have extended my answer; it was too short.